# Design principle of components

Tags: material-ui

I would like to ask a question about the design principles of the components listed in MUI.
I find the MUI components very useful, especially “Data Grid” which seems to cover a great variety of use cases.
So wanted to ask if these components are created based on a design principle?
I would really appreciate if you can tell me anything about what design principles you use for components. especially from an implementation point of view.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for design principles behind the Material UI library, they come from [Google Material Design](https://material.io/components/data-tables)

If you're looking for more 'how do I pick which component to use from this large library for my use case?' then it comes from experience.
If you were designing and implementing a button, you could use:

- ButtonBase component: Comes with no styles so you can add your own from scratch.
- Button component: The standard out of the box component that uses your default primary theme.
- IconButton: If you have an action that needs no text to describe, I'd reach for a simple icon button e.g. download or save have very recognizable icons

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   
  
I could find design principles at Google Material Design.  
  
It seems each component has own principle, e.g) "Organized, Interactive, intuitive"  as an example of "Data table".  
I'm wondering if there is  a "base principle" common in all components.